# Times tables in python

Tags: python, loops, multiplication

I decided to write software to make my little brother do his times tables, So I wrote the following code:

```
for i in range(13):
        for j in range(13):
            print(i, '*', j, '=')
            A = input(" ")
            while A != i*j:
                print(i, '*', j, '=')
                A = input(" ")
            else:
                print("Correct")
```

I have found that it keeps giving me 0 * 0 = and does not continue on to the next question when I run this code, please tell me what I am doing wrong

Comment: You might want to take a look at codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I just tried running this in 2.x and it works perfectly for me. 0*0, 0*1, 0*2 etc

Comment: `range()` will start at 0 unless you provide the lower bound. `for i in range(1,13)` for example

Comment: Are using Python 3.x? If so `input` returns a string and `A` will require a *cast* to int

Answer (score 1):

It is failing because of this line:

```
while A != i*j:
```

`A` is a string. `i*j` is not a string. This will cause the conditional to fail. It is doing this comparison:

```
>>> 0 == "0"
False
```

To fix this, you can cast `A` as an `int` (since you are doing integer multiplication)

```
while int(A) != i*j:
```